# I can't download Java or WINE due to similiar error

Tags: apt, updates, wine, java, dpkg

I've been trying to download Java Oracle 8 and WINE and I keep getting the same problem.

> W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

I get this when I try installing both and I've been searching for a solution, but I can't find one. Then there's this problem:

> dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory

What's that mean and ho do I fix it?

---

Ok, it doesn't show that error anymore, thank you to all of you. I really appreciate the help. I have a next question though...

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liboxideqtcore0 : Depends: oxideqt-codecs (= 1.0.0~bzr501-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed or
                            oxideqt-codecs-extra (= 1.0.0~bzr501-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.19-0ubuntu2~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.19-0ubuntu2~trusty2) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I did the command and it said something about /var/lib/dpkg/lock, so I go there and can't open the file. I am trying to install WINE 1.7 for Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: From what it looks like, Ubuntu won't need to be reinstalled. However, your problem is not average...I'll take a closer look at this situation.

Answer (score 0):

this message means that you some broken URLs in packages list, you have to edit the list and remove those URLs, to do that open: **/etc/apt/sources.list** and save the file after editing it. then try to update again.

to understand apt-get command more follow http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man8/apt-get.8.html

Answer (score -1):

That error means you've screwed up the packages lists. Find the line in /etc/sources.list with dl.google.com on it and delete the whole line. Make sure to run sudo apt-get update afterwards, or it won't work.

Comment: What do you mean "find the line in /etc/sources.list?" Sorry i'm new to this stuff.

Comment: Open gedit (the text editor), press open, go to computer, then click etc, then click sources.list,  then open it, then use Ctrl+F to find dl.google.com, then delete that line. Then you can use sudo apt-get update

Comment: There is no sources.list, I looked thoroughly. Is there anyway to add it on?

Comment: sudo gedit /etc/sources.list

Comment: Are you sure that's what the problem is? I have to use the terminal to open the sources.list, and there's NOTHING on it. Should I add anything to it? I saved changes with nothing on it and did sudo apt-get update but then it said the same thing as before.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: Try /etc/apt/sources.list?